# Как сменить кодировку в файле на Python

Tags: python

```py
import os
os.system('netsh wlan show profiles name=Rostelecom_Inactivated key=clear>seti.txt')
```

Возможно ли сразу здесь сменить кодировку на UTF-8?

Comment: Запустить `netsh` с помощью `Popen`, прочитать вывод, перекодировать из cp866 в utf-8 и записать в файл средствами Python.

Comment: Спасибо большое